# Google doesn't know everything

Tags: knowledge

The obscure lits are playing in town. The Mouse on the sensory-syrynx, Colin on the pianocktail but who is playing the Undecagonstring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this would be

> Pyan the familiar

The question refers to

> Fictional musical instruments and their audiences

Specifically, the Mouse on the sensory-syrinx is

> a reference to [Samuel R. Delaney's Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_(novel)#Characters) the Mouse first listens to Leo playing the sensory-syrinx.

and Colin on the pianocktail is

> a reference to [Boris Vian's Ecume des Jours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froth_on_the_Daydream), Colin observes the junctiquarian play Blues of the Vagabond and drinks the ensuing concoction.

and the undecagonstring

> features in the late [Iain M. Banks's Hydrogen Sonata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hydrogen_Sonata) under its full name the antagonistic undecagonstring. Pyan's owner Vyr Cossont of the band "The Lords of Excrement" has grown two extra arms to play the Hydrogen Sonata, but AFAIK Pyan is the only being present at its performance.

Comment: Thus proving that if 'Google doesn't know everything', then Wikipedia does!

Comment: And there I was hoping Google would provide the names of the books but you would have to check physical copies of them to get the full answer. Well done.

Comment: … and in fact, that is what I did.